How to handle switching between windows (GUIs) in Python Tkinter?
Please help to resolve the issue in my Tkinter code… Actually, I want to switch between to widows (multiple times from window1 to window2 and backforht). I am using Python Tkinter gui library.
Problem Statement:
I have a simple tkinter logIn page that contains a login button. On clicking this button, I want to close this login page and wants to open (or run) a new python file that displays main project GUI (that contains many tkinter widgets buttons, text boxes, labels etc.). Further, on this main GUI, I have a “Back to Login Window” Button. When i click this button then I want to close this main GUI page and wants to display again Login page. Upto this stage, my code do as i want (code is working as i desires).
BUT,after this when I again, Press login button to close it and expects main GUI to open but not successfull…....My login page get closes but this does not open main GUI page again (in fact whole project gets closed)…why it so? please help me.
(1) I have made a small project with two python files, with names MultiWindowsLogIn.py and the other is mainGUI.py.
(2) Code of MultiWindowsLogIn.py is as:
from tkinter import *

def login():
    logInWindow.quit()
    logInWindow.destroy()
    import mainGUI

logInWindow = Tk()
logInWindow.title(“Login Window Title”)
logInWindow.geometry(‘600x400’)

logInButton = Button(logInWindow, text=“Login”, width=15, font=(‘times new roman’, 15, ‘bold’), bd=2, command=login)
logInButton.place(x=200,y=250)

logInWindow.mainloop()

(3) Code of mainGUI.py is as:
from tkinter import *



def backToLoginPage():
    guiWindow.quit()
    guiWindow.destroy()
    import MultiWindowsLogIn
 
guiWindow = Tk()
guiWindow.title(“Student Registration System”)
guiWindow.geometry(‘500x200+0+0’)

backButton = Button(guiWindow, text=“Back to Login Window”, font=(‘times new roman’, 15, ‘bold’), bd=3, command=backToLoginPage)
backButton.place(x=150, y=100)


guiWindow.mainloop()

Please help me to solve the issue, If there is some other way to achieve the desired output then please let me know.

don't switch windows but create two Frame with different widgets and replace these Frame in one window - using pack() and pack_forget() or grid() and grid_forget(). In some answers you can see examples which use it and they use name Page for these Frames

Python remembers what you already imported and it will NOT import the same file again - so it will not run again the same code which is NOT in function. You have to keep code in function(s) - ie. start_window() - and use MultiWindowsLogIn.start_window() and  mainGUI.start_window(). But maybe it would be simpler if you would create new scripts which imports MultiWindowsLogIn and mainGUI and it controls when to run MultiWindowsLogIn.start_window() or mainGUI.start_window()

When Python runs import then it checks if this module was already imported and it doesn't import it again - so it can't run code with is NOT in functions and it can't run your script again.
You have to keep code in functions to run it again.
In this code I keep code in functions run() and it use main.run() to start again main window, and login_window.run() to start again login window.
main.py
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import login_window

def back_to_login_page():  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    main_window.quit()
    main_window.destroy()
    login_window.run()
    
def run(): 
    global main_window
    global back_button
    
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    main_window.title('Student Registration System')
    main_window.geometry('500x200+0+0')

    back_button = tk.Button(main_window, text='Back to Login Window', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=3, command=back_to_login_page)
    back_button.place(x=150, y=100)

    main_window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()    

login_window.py
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import main

def login():
    login_window.quit()
    login_window.destroy()
    main.run()
    
def run():
    global login_window
    global login_button
    
    login_window = tk.Tk()
    login_window.title('Login Window Title')
    login_window.geometry('600x400')

    login_button = tk.Button(login_window, text='Login', width=15, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=2, command=login)
    login_button.place(x=200, y=250)

    login_window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()


But I think more popular method is to keep widgets in Frame and use only one window Tk() and replace one Frame with other Frame using .pack() and .pack_forget() or .grid() and .grid_forget(). This way both windows (or rather both Frame are all time in memory so you can get values from one Frame and put it in another Frame - and when you show again some Frame then you can see previous values in Entry() or Text()
Here code in one file
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- main_page ----    

def create_main_frame(master):
    global back_button
    
    frame = tk.Frame(master)
    back_button = tk.Button(frame, text='Back to Login Window', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=3, command=back_to_login_page)
    back_button.place(x=150, y=100)

    return frame

def show_main_frame():
    window.title('Student Registration System')
    window.geometry('500x200+0+0')
    
    main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

def back_to_login_page():  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    main_frame.pack_forget()
    show_login_frame()

# --- login_page ----    

def create_login_frame(master):
    global login_button
    
    frame = tk.Frame(master)
    login_button = tk.Button(frame, text='Login', width=15, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=2, command=login)
    login_button.place(x=200, y=250)
    
    return frame

def show_login_frame():
    window.title('Login Window Title')
    window.geometry('600x400')
    
    login_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

def login():
    login_frame.pack_forget()
    show_main_frame()

# --------------------------------------
    
def run(): 
    global window
    global main_frame
    global login_frame
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    
    main_frame = create_main_frame(window)
    login_frame = create_login_frame(window)

    show_main_frame()
    
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()    


EDIT:
You can find many answers which use the same solution with class Page()
For example first answer in python - Switch between two frames in tkinter? - Stack Overflow
I made simpler example - without BasePage
It uses dictionary window.pages to keep all pages - and other pages has access using self.master.pages
It also uses dictionary window.config to keep shared information - and all pages can access them using self.master.config. For example LoginPage can set information about logged in user - and other pages may use it to display information.
main_page.py
import tkinter as tk

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='???', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=3)
        self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.33, anchor='center')
    
        self.back_button = tk.Button(self, text='Back to Login Window', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=3, 
                                        command=self.back_to_login_page)
        self.back_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.66, anchor='center')

    def show(self):
        self.master.title('Student Registration System')
        self.master.geometry('500x200+0+0')
    
        self.label['text'] = f"USERNAME: {self.master.config['username']}"
        
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def back_to_login_page(self):
        self.pack_forget()
        self.master.pages['login'].show()

login_page.py
import tkinter as tk

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.username_label = tk.Label(self, text="USERNAME", width=15, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=2) 
        self.username_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, anchor='center')

        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=15, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=2) 
        self.username_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    
        self.login_button = tk.Button(self, text='Login', width=15, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=2, 
                                        command=self.login)
        self.login_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor='center')

    def show(self):
        self.master.title('Login Window Title')
        self.master.geometry('600x400')
    
        #self.username_entry.delete(0, 'end')  # remove previous text
        
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def login(self):
        self.master.config['logged_id'] = True
        self.master.config['username'] = self.username_entry.get()
        
        self.pack_forget()
        self.master.pages['main'].show()

main.py
import tkinter as tk
from main_page import MainPage
from login_page import LoginPage
  
def run(): 
    
    window = tk.Tk()

    # assign dictionary to `window` so pages will have easy access to config using `self.master.config`
    window.config = {
        'logged_in': False,
        'username': '',
    }

    # assign dictionary to `window` so pages will have easy access to other pages using `self.master.pages`
    window.pages = {    
        'main' :  MainPage(window),
        'login': LoginPage(window),
    }
    
    window.pages['main'].show()
    
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()    


thanks Furas for your comprehensive reply.......your reply Especially a running example you prepared is worthwhile.

thanks Furas for your comprehensive reply.......your reply Especially a running example you prepared is worthwhile. One more question, please. For this solution we have to place all code in one file which is ok for small application, but for a large complex GUI (or multipages with many widgets) it will become difficult to manage/readibility /maintainability issues.............

for bigger code it would be simpler to keep every page as class - and then you can keep this page in separated file. There are some answers which show example code with class Page(tk.Frame) - see python - Switch between two frames in tkinter? - Stack Overflow. In first answer you can see more links

I added code which keeps pages in separated files but as classes. It also use window.config to share data between pages. When you put username on LoginPage then it will display it on MainPage
